# Downgrade iPad 2 from iOS 6 to iOS 5 using DFU mode

Tags: ipad, ios

I want to downgrade my iPad 2 from iOS 6 to 5.1 because Maps is useless. I read articles saying that you need to have saved the SHSH blobs to be able to do so, which I didn't, but I haven't seen any article talking about DFU mode. Has Apple restricted the use of DFU mode? Previously, I was able to downgrade an iPad using DFU mode, even if it's not officially supported. Note that I do not want to jailbreak my device. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

DFU is something built into the hardware, so the iPad 2 firmware could modify this, but I would presume it's even lower level and not something you can change. There are no reports that iOS 6 has stopped DFU, so it's very likely something else has happened.

I don't think Apple ever has released an iOS DFU article, but there certainly hasn't been one for the last two or more years, so I don't think that has changed either.